# Hamerspoon run script by cli/terminal

Tags: hammerspoon

I am writing in the `init.lua` script.

```
function openObsidianAndSearch()
    -- Open Obsidian
    hs.application.launchOrFocus("Obsidian")
    
    -- Wait for a moment to ensure Obsidian has focus
    hs.timer.doAfter(1, function()
        -- Send Cmd+Shift+F to Obsidian
        hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd", "shift"}, "F")
    end)
end
```

I want to run it from the terminal.

```
hs -c 'openObsidianAndSearch()'
fish: Unknown command: hs
```

I installed Hammerspoon by `brew install --cask hammerspoon`.